Is there any way to open wpf (webView) context menu in the same window on new tab
I am trying to open my extension in existing window on new tabs
chrome extension have its own property like:
// In Chrome to open on new window
chrome.windows.create({
            focused: true,
            'url': urlToOpen
        })
//In Chrome to open on active tab
        chrome.tabs.update({'url': urlToOpen})
// In Chrome to open in existing window on new tab
         chrome.tabs.create({
             'url': urlToOpen
         })

But when i am trying to open on my wpf webview form (chrome.tabs.create) it will open the new window not open the new tabs how i can resolve it?
I try this:
// In Chrome to open on new window
chrome.windows.create({
            focused: true,
            'url': urlToOpen
        })
//In Chrome to open on active tab
        chrome.tabs.update({'url': urlToOpen})
// In Chrome to open in existing window on new tab
         chrome.tabs.create({
             'url': urlToOpen
         })

And i want to open from context menu on new tab in wpf webview

chrome.windows.create({.....}, wnd=>{ chrome.tabs.create({url: '...', windowId: wnd.id}) })
